# Infowindow for circular marker in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Problem  :I am trying to get a info Window on click of circular marker in Google Map .

My Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Circle Simple</title>

<style type="text/css">
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%
}
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var citymap = {};
citymap['Yelahanka'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.133754,77.585784),
  population: 2842518
};
citymap['Dodaballarpur'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(15.133754,77.585784),
  population: 8143197
};
citymap['Mekricircle'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.133754,77.585784),
  population: 3844829
}
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.133754,77.585784),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);


  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
  'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
  'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
  '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
  'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
  'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
  'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
  'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
  'Heritage Site.</p>'+
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
  'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';




  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  for (var city in citymap) {

    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 6,
      fillColor: '#669999',
      fillOpacity: 0.45,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].population / 200
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addListener(populationOptions,'click', function() {
      alert("i am here in this infowindow");
      infowindow.open(map,populationOptions );
    });
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the circular marker it doesnot respond and I dont get any infowindow. In the above code i am trying to create a dynamic circle around place with infowindow showing some details on click of the circular region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code to create the infoWindow. In the Loc variable generate the location by passing the longitude and the latitude parameters where the infowindow needs to open up.

```
var Loc = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        var INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH = 352;                                
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        position :Loc,
        maxWidth: INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle,'click', function() {
                                                infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                                infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,0)});
                                                infowindow.open(map,this);
             });
```

Comment: To get infoWindow displayed in the GoogleMap for a continous geometry specific lat, long has to be passed on to infowindow .Though I got my code bit differently .

Answer (score 0):

The object you are passing to the event listener seems incorrect. Please use the following code to attach onClick event on 'cityCircle'.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle,'click', function() {
      alert("i am here in this infowindow");
      infowindow.open(map,populationOptions );
    });
```

Comment: is it giving that alert message ?

Comment: okay..now atleast connecting to the onclick...i think there is some issue with parameters passed for opening infoWindow